# How to add or suffix spaces in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, xslt-1.0, bi-publisher

looking for syntax how to add or suffix extra spaces in xslt 1.0.

i am working on ISO2022cgi payment template. i have customized the template as bank requirement.
we have to send data with 35 characters length so bank can consider 36th character as new line.
so bank expecting extra spaces to suffix.

eg: 'data           '
when i tried to include spaces the xml output provide single space. tired non breaking values like
  and   this is providing required spaces but , bank not accepting hex values.

need a help here how to pad or suffix spaces in xslt.
thanks
Ram

Comment: Is it possible to give just a little bit of an example?

Answer (score 1):

This is for XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces35" select="'                                   '"/>

<xsl:variable name="test" select="'Pad this'"/>

<!-- Do this is the you want to padr and the max number of spaces you want is 35.  -->  
<xsl:variable name="padr35" select="substring(concat($test, $spaces35), 1, 35)"/>

<!-- This is padding right 35 but the final string length can be more than 35, if the input string is longer than 35.  -->
<xsl:variable name="PaddingR35" select="concat($test, substring($spaces35, 1, 35 - string-length($test)))"/>
```

Comment: I agree with that and I was going to give a very similar example; however, I'm not sure that the OP was having problem with string padding or with whitespace serialization in XML output.

Comment: @al.truisme.  Good point...  He is asking for "extra spaces" to pad the data to 35 characters.  So, that's what I went with...  I guess it's part of his serializing process.  If he needs more, he can let us know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks John for your input. i have tried the above one. when i open the xml output in browser i can see there is one space. but same output if i open in notepad++ i can see the required spaces. can i know why is that difference. thanks.-Ram

Comment: If I were to speculate, I would say that your browser is trimming the trailing spaces.  Probably because trailing spaces are usually meaningless in a browser.  Maybe there's a setting for leaving them there...  Also, could be the trailing spaces are getting removed somewhere else along the line...  That said, the important question is are the spaces there when the data arrives at the bank.  If so, problem solved.  Also, if you like the answer I gave you, please click the up triangle next to the answer.  Good luck!